# c++ struct and container

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am writing a small software which deals with inter-process multicast. For each message, on each process, I have a couple of variables assigned to the message itself:

```
messageID
senderID
ack1
ack2
ack3
...
```

I would like to put these elements (which are many) in a container, so that it is later easy to perform operations such as changing the value of `ack1` for a given `messageID` (I should keep trace of which processes in my group notified me that they got the message).

Which is the best container to use in this case?

Thanks

Comment: Are your MessageIDs unique identifiers for each message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) or [boost::unordered_map](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) (soon to be standard) as you can access it by message id.
Next time you'd want to answer such a question alone, take a look at [this diagram](http://adrinael.net/containerchoice).

Comment: Thanks for the diagram, too! :)

Comment: @Danilo The appropriate way to acknowledge a good answer is an upvote in stackoverflow. You are more than welcome to do so :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map to easily fetch a structure by `messageID`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

Comment: boost::multi_map or c++0x multimap.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `std::map` and `boost::unordered_map`, if you plan to iterate over the messages from a given `senderID` you can use [`boost::multi_index_container`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).